# Q: Basics of counting using rule of product

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Lets say in a certain Univ, we are selecting committee members.
Dep A has 10,
Dep B has 15, and 
Dep C has 20 persons.

How many ways can we select a committee if there should be

a) 2 persons, and they should be from different departments.
b) 2 persons, both from the same department.
c) 2 persons (from any department)

I read over the whole chapter and solved nearly all of the example questions, but I can't still figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)

If Dep A and Dep B send one rep, there are 10*15=150 possiblities,

for Dep A and Dep C, there are 10*20=200 possibilities,

for Dep B and Dep C, there are 15*20=300 possibilities,

so a total of **550** possibilities.

b) If both are from Dep A, there are $\binom{10}2=\frac{10\cdot 9}{2} =45$ possibilities. You divide by 2 because you don't want to count each pair twice.

For Dep B, there are $\binom{15}2=\frac{15\cdot 14}{2} =105$ possibilites,

and for Dep C, there are $\binom{20}2=\frac{20\cdot 19}{2} =190$ possibilites,

so a total of **340** possibilities.

c) If it doesn't matter where they come from there are simply $\binom{45}2=\frac{45\cdot 44}{2} =\mathbf{990}$ possiblities.

Comment: Why did you add up the numbers for b)? I'm little confused here.

Comment: Because you asked "How many ways can we select a committee if ...". That meant to me that we have to add all the different possibilities